# How to configure Duktape?

Tags: android, configure, duktape

Duktape doesn't seem to have Android as a platform out of the box.
How should i configure it to be able to build a native c/c++ shared library out of it myself, to be run on Android?
Please let me know the different flags to get it to configure and compile with the smallest sized library file.

Answer (score 0):

Square currently maintains an android version of Duktape. https://github.com/square/duktape-android

Just add the following gradle dependency to your project: compile 'com.squareup.duktape:duktape-android:1.2.0'

Comment: I know. But I'm looking for the c/c++ native code only. Without the java parts, and to be able to build it myself since duktape-android uses duktape 1.8 while there's already 2+

Comment: Please specify that in the question